# Неправильная работа программы с Firebird

Tags: python, firebird, sql

Написал программу для создания таблицы в базе данных

```
os.remove('D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb')
con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb'  user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'")
conn=kinterbasdb.connect(host='localhost',database='D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
cur=conn.cursor()
s="""
create table CLIENTS
(
  ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  COMPANY   CHAR(50),
  "LAST NAME"   CHAR(50),
  "FIRST NAME"   CHAR(50),
  "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   CHAR(50),
  "JOB TITLE"   CHAR(50),
  "BUSINESS PHONE"    CHAR(25),
  "HOME PHONE"   CHAR(25),
  "MOBILE PHONE"   CHAR(25),
  "FAX NUMBER"   CHAR(25),
  ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
  CITY   VARCHAR(50),
  "STATE/PROVINCE"   CHAR(50),
  "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   CHAR(15),
  "COUNTRY/REGION"   CHAR(50),
  "WEB-SITE"   CHAR(25),
  NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
  INCLUDING   BLOB
);
"""
print s
cur.execute(s)
con.close()
conn.close()
print "Connect succesfully"
```

Но после открытия соответствующей базы данных в IBExpert не нахожу ни одной таблицы. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**COMMIT**  таблицу создали, а комит забыли